# How to show windows form when a custom ribbon button is clicked

Tags: vba, basic

I am creating a Word Addin using Visual Studio 2008 with Visual Basic language. I have created a custom ribbon group and a  button name "Show_Form". I want that when I click on that button a windows form named "Form" will show.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Form.show()

End Sub
```

It showing a error. Can you please help me.

[image]

Comment: You do not have an object called "Form", that's the name of the object class. Try with "Form1", "Form2" or "Form3" depending on the one you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

There is no form called "Form"

You will need to do Form1.Show or Form2.Show etc

However it is good practice to name the forms to what they will be used for otherwise it can become difficult to understand the program code if everything is named so that it doesn't actually identify what it does.